Martial arts cartoon in which the protagonists are a girl and two boys; the girl wears pink clothes and can control water
The protagonists are one girl and two boys (if I remember correctly). The girl can control water, but I don't remember about the boys. Her clothes are pink (I believe). They are fighting against a dark shadow thing that's sealed in a dungeon.
In one of the episodes, the girl is taken control of by that dark shadow thing when she went alone. Then, it shows that when they turn adult, the girl will lead an attack and kill the boys (or at least defeat them).
The cartoon is 2D and is related to martial arts. The art is not chibi (its characters have realistic proportions). The clothing and background is probably like Ancient China?

In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, was this a series or a movie? And are there any similar cartoons that you can rule out?

Is this Shaolin Wuzang (2006)...?

Set in Ancient China, three teenagers are admitted into the most prestigious school of kung fu: the Temple of Shaolin. But they don't know that they are the reincarnation of three Shaolin monks who a thousand years earlier gave their life to neutralize the worst demon. This demon is back now and our three heroes will have to destroy it while initiating themselves with the art of kung fu.

The three protagonists mentioned in the plot summary above are Hua, a girl, Tang, a boy, and Cheng, another boy. Hua wears pink clothing and seems to have water powers (first demonstrated in episode 2), although she doesn't use them often or for long as her teenage self and relies moreso on a whip.


Shaolin Wuzang - S01E05 - "The River-Dragons"

In episode 9, she and the two boys are exploring a cave when she gets separated from them and subsequently captured by the main antagonist of the show, Hei Hu, an ancient demon who uses the masked body of an old woman as a vessel. The boys are then transported to the future by an artefact called the Wheel of Time and witness their adult selves fighting an adult version of Hua, who now serves Hei Hu and seems much more powerful than before, using her water powers to send them running.



